# For Laravel + React application which is better, REST API calls or blade included react component?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native

Working on laravel + react project and need your suggestions for use of REST API calls. Are REST API calls will be the better option than importing React components inside blade?

Note: We are planning for mobile application as well using React native so please do consider this as well.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: REST Api based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending on using this for mobile REST API calls are you're best bet. This way you can use the same backend for the mobile side. It's a little more work up front but its a highly flexible setup moving forward. Plus you can expose REST API end points to customers or vendors its a great option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Larvel Blades with React Native, Larvel blades render html server side, React native doesn't render HTML it renders native UI components, the fact that they are written like HTML in code is misleading, that is why you have to import each component in React Native because the render message is not simply HTML markdown like React for the web.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use the react laravel blade 
if you want to use something like that try vue.js